# this.context.router is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                    <Nav className='float_right'>
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <LinkContainer to='/about'>
                                <NavItem>
                                    About us
                                </NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutComponent}/>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={HomeComponent}/>
                </Switch>
            </React.Fragment>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

And I'm trying to make a simple navigation. But I'm getting an error saying:

> TypeError: this.context.router is undefined

Why is that? I checked the docs and searched for the answer, but all I found was to add something with the context to the constructor, like

```
constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
}
```

This started happening when I added `<LinkContainer/>` to the code

Which just didn't work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What versions of react-router and react-router-bootstrap are you using

Comment: "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
Taken from package.json